# ruby tests - error messages don't include line numbers or file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get line numbers to be reported with my errors when testing. Here is what I get back on a typical error:

```
josh@josh-laptop:~/d/test$ ruby unit/line_test.rb -n test_update
Loaded suite unit/line_test
Started
E
Finished in 0.066663 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_update(LineTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `sdf' for
#<LineTest:0xb6e61304>


1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

It is tough to debug without a line number and filename. From the code
samples I've seen, people generally get back a more verbose error
reports. How do I enable this?

Thanks!

[Edit] From the Rails Guide

```
$ ruby unit/post_test.rb -n test_should_report_error
Loaded suite -e
Started
E
Finished in 0.082603 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_should_report_error(PostTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `some_undefined_variable' for #<PostTest:0x249d354>
    /test/unit/post_test.rb:6:in `test_should_report_error'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

Comment: How about showing a stripped down version of your test code. I've used Test::Unit, RSpec, Shoulda and ZenTest at different times and all have given me line numbers with the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that I don't like but which gets the job done. I thought I'd post it in case others can't find a better solution

```
ruby -d unit/line_test.rb -n test_update
```

-d sets the $DEBUG to true and gives a dump with error, warning, exception details

Answer (score 0):

How long are your unit tests? Typically, a test case should only be a couple of lines of code. If not, consider splitting it up. That should really narrow it down, particularly for an undefined variable or method. In any case, if you install ruby-debug, you can step through the test case and see exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: my tests aren't long. but, if you get something like ArgumentError it seems silly to have to check all function calls

Comment: I guess I don't see how much more the stack trace would give you other than a ton of noise for each failing test. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: sorry, i just saw this. it gives you the line number and file things crashed in. the noise is annoying but doesn't really get in the way because the offending line is the last in the trace.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Rails app? Then most likely [Rails' backtrace cleaner](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html) is getting in the way. Most likely because your directory starts with "unit" not "test" like Rails assumes. I ran into a similar issue (a plugin I was developing was outside the Rails directory so the entire backtrace was being filtered).

Check out the [default silencer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb#L15) and either add a filter so that it will pass this silencer (filters run before silencers) OR simply remove the silencer with [remove_silencers!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html#method-i-remove_silencers-21). Rails provides [a file in the initializers directory](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb#L7) that will do this but the line is commented out by default.